# assign coordinates with for loop in 2d array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Simply I want to assign x-coordinate and y-coordinate with for loops.But It is not working like another language like c#,c++.This is my code:

```
  var coordinate=[[]];
  var x, y;
      for (x=1; x <= 7; x += 1) {
          for (y=1; y <= 5; y += 1) {
              coordinate[x][y] = "("+x+","+y+")";
          }
      }
```

How can I make this?

Comment: What result do you get now? What is your desired result? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: @musefan jsbin.com => "error"
"TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
    at bajazudako.js:7:30
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.39.11.min.js:1:13926
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.39.11.min.js:1:10855"

Comment: Also, just saying, but it's a very strange requirement to have a 2D array with just string in

Comment: you can copy paste jsbin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var coordinate=[];
  var x, y;
      for (x=1; x <= 7; x += 1) {
            coordinate[x] = [];
          for (y=1; y <= 5; y += 1) {
              coordinate[x][y] = "("+x+","+y+")";
          }
      }
```

Comment: It is working but complicated.Why we have to write coordinate[x]=[]; ?

Comment: It's just new Array literal. It means that this array element will be another array, which totally makes sense :) We have to do it, because JS doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays native.